# How to integrate razorpay with expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am trying to integrate razorpay with my expo project but i am getting an error which is ->
[image]

this is the code i am trying

```
         <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
            var options = {
              description: "Credits towards consultation",
              image: "https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png",
              currency: "INR",
              key: "test_api_key", // Your api key
              amount: "5000",
              name: "foo",
              prefill: {
                email: "void@razorpay.com",
                contact: "9191919191",
                name: "Razorpay Software",
              },
              theme: { color: "#F37254" },
            };
            RazorpayCheckout.open(options).then((data) => {
              // handle success
              alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);
            }).catch((error) => {
              // handle failure
              alert(error);
            });
        }}
        >
          <Text>Pay to me</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Please go though the discussion (https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-for-razorpay). I think you have to eject expo project.

Comment: @Balu can you tell me what you exactly mean by ejecting and is there any way i can convert my code to react native,  also i think that they are not vert different (expo and native) so using my existing code and building react native code will take how much of time do you have any idea brother , please let me know , thank you for your response.

Comment: I mean when you use expo we can't add Native modules. If you want to add Native modules you have to eject expo.  check this bout expo eject <https://docs.expo.dev/expokit/eject/>. In your case If you want to use razorpay in your project you should use React native CLI  or eject expo project to add Native modules. because razor pay does not support managed expo.

Comment: okay i get it, i will try this , thanks mate.